# jquery always coloured link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day, I need to make that when user click on link it need to change color from black to red and make coloured all the time until the user click another link and then another link mark as red and this changed to black. I user jquery+css, but it's work not correct

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a")
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#d20e10");
        });
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: You want the background color of the text or the font text?

Comment: there is no `anchor` tag in your code.

Comment: Since clicking a link triggers the browser to load a new page, you can't use an 'onclick' event. You'll need to use an 'active class' on your menu items (for example with PHP).

Comment: @LinkinTED - unless he returns false or uses preventDefault() with the click event to cancel the default behavior.

Comment: I will try to use :visited pseudo-class but it's still isnt work

Comment: You are using the `mouseenter` event instead of `onclick`, is this what you intended?

Comment: @j08691, that's true. @Rakstit, the `:visited` pseudo class only styles the links (/pages) that you have visited. Not the active one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to complete the markup. There are no anchors.
Second, you need to avoid the anchor default behaviour, in case they point to a different page.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a").on('click', function(e) {
        // Comment off the line below if the anchors are
        // not pointing to a different page
        e.preventDefault();

        // Set all back to black, but the clicked one which becomes red
        $("li a").css("color", "red").not($(this)).css("color", "black");
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LWagy/

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some html for this to work.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("li a").css("background-color", "#000");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#d20e10");
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not exactly what i need, it's change color only when hover over the link

Comment: You want the link to change color to red on mouse enter then change back on mouse leave?

Answer (score 0):

if I understands you correctly try using this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("li a")
        .click(function(){
            $("li a").css('color', 'black');
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First `anchor` tag is missing.

2) Are you using `jQuery` library reference?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

3) `mouseenter` !== `click`

4) `background-color` !== `color`

Finally try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li a")
        .click(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#d20e10");
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/4DCR2/)

---

if **hovering** is what you need, then try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li a")
        .hover(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#d20e10");
        }, function() {
            $(this).css("color", "#000000");
        });
});
```

[**JSFiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4DCR2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not that difficult. All you need to is use `click` of jquery .

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id ='li1'>1</li>
    <li id='li2'>2</li>
    <li id='li3'>3</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#li1")
        .click(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#d20e10");
            $("#li2").css("background-color", "white");
            $("#li3").css("background-color", "white");
        });

    $("#li2")
        .click(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#d20e10");
            $("#li3").css("background-color", "white");
            $("#li1").css("background-color", "white");
        });

    $("#li3")
        .click(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#d20e10");
            $("#li2").css("background-color", "white");
            $("#li1").css("background-color", "white");
        });
});
```

See the accompanying jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Bpywh/

Comment: And if it's a `hover` you want, then use `jquery hover` instead of `click`. Voila !